# Select All MySQL Rows

Tags: php, mysql, database, rows

I have the following code which choose all rows in MYSQL but it show the last row only

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`") or die(mysql_error());
     while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
          {
          $token = $row['instagram_access_token'];
          }
          echo "$token";
```

Comment: You keep overwriting the value of `$m` in your loop

Comment: You're only storing the last row. Make $m an array or concatenate it.

Comment: You can use  $m[]=$row['instagram_access_token']; and use print_r($m) as @chris85 suggested.

Comment: You shouldn't be using mysql_* functions because they are depreciated, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-i-shouldnt-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Your code echo last row because, within `while` loop every time you overwrites `$token` value with new value. Try to connect using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) & assign variable to array like this.

```
 $token=[];
 $user='your_user_name';
 $pass='your_password';
 $conn= new PDO('mysql:host=your_host_name;dbname=your_db_name', $user, $pass);
 $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users`');
 $query->execute();
// alternatively you could use PDOStatement::fetchAll() and get rid of the loop
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $token[] = $row['instagram_access_token']; // see this line with []
}

 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($token);
 echo '</pre>';
```

**Note:** Don't use **mysql_*** see more here [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-i-shouldnt-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: @BigRabbit OP is using mysql_* this is just an answer to the question.

Comment: @chris85, yaap , i know , i am going to edit my answer & put the total connection code with `PDO`, thanx

Comment: @BigRabbit Is answering a question for the general public better than answering the specific question asked? I think noting the user should use mysqli or PDO sufficed.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY RAND()") or    
    die(mysql_error());
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{
    $m = $row['instagram_access_token'];
    echo "$m";
}
```

Comment: Why not simply echo $row['instagram_access_token'];? Why to assign to $m just for echo ?

Comment: Concatenate or make it an array I think is a better solution. Then it will be accessible later if needed.

Comment: You can echo directly or maybe the question is simplified and instead of echoing the user needs to do something else with that data

Comment: @LelioFaieta - yes; but the values in `$row` are re-set every time the loop runs. If you want to access them outside the loop, then assigning the contents to another array will let you do that.